# Coordinate Geometry - Distance Formula

Tags: geometry

If the points $A(4,3)$ and $B(x,5)$ are on the circle with center $O(2,3)$ find the value of $x$.

Since $AO=BO$
Using distance formula,
we get $x=2$

However my approach was why can't section formula be used where $(2,3)$ can be considered as the midpoint so that 
$M = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}$

I can't figure out the reason why this method doesn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That would require the line segment $AB$ to be the diameter for $M$ to be equal to $O$ which is not necessarily true.

It is possible that $AB$ doesn't pass through $O$.

Answer (score 0):

Note : $AB$ is a chord.

Midpoint: $M=(x/2+2,,4)$.

1) Slope $AB$:

$m_1:= \dfrac{5-3}{x-4}=\dfrac{2}{x-4}$.

2) Slope $MO$:

$m_2:= \dfrac {4-3}{x/2+2 -2}=2/x.$

$m_1$ is perpendicular to $m_2$ (why?):

$m_1m_2=-1.$

Hence $x/2-2=- x/2;$

$x=2$

Answer (score 0):

You should sketch it on the cooredinate plane.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

If $A(4,3)$ lies on the circle with center $O(2,3)$, then $AO=2$ is the radius.

The point $B(x,5)$ lies somewhere on the blue line $y=5$. In order for $B$ to lie on the circle too, it must be a common (touching or intersection) point of the circle and the blue line. And we see it is the touching point $B(2,5)$.

When you consider $M(2,3)$ as the middle point of $AB$ and calculate $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}=\frac{4+x}{2}=2 \Rightarrow x=0$, you will find the point $C(0,3)$ which is on the circle, but it is not on the blue line. Also, $\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}=\frac{3+5}{2}=4\ne 3$.